# How to get displayed text location (in terms of pixels) on my screen?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, display, display-manager

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to read different words displayed on computer screen. For example in home folder (in GUI mode), we have Downloads, Documents etc. To display these words, there must be some pixel wise information inside OS.

Is there any system calls using which we can know the starting pixel location of each word displayed on computer screen? Is it possible with any other technique? Suggestions using examples will be very useful.

Comment: No, there is no generic way to determine this. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: @dobey, I am trying to read words displayed on computer screen required for another application. If there is no generic way, then please tell some specific way.

Comment: It depends on what your goal is. If you [edit] your question to more clearly express your goal, it's easier to provide something more helpful as an answer. As the question is now, the answer is basically "no you can't do that."